# AVAudioEngine: filter realtime audio

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioengine

I have gone through the Apple [Sample Code on Equalizing Audio with vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/equalizing_audio_with_vdsp), where the audio file is filtered in  `AVAudioSourceNode`  and reproduced.

My objective is to do exactly the same, but instead of taking the audio from an audio file, take it in real-time from the microphone. Is it possible to do so in `AVAudioEngine`? A couple of ways to do so are based on `installTap` or `AVAudioSinkNode`, as described in *First strategy* and *Second strategy* sections.

So far, I got a bit closer to my objective with the following 2 strategies.

###### First strategy

```
// Added new class variables
private lazy var sinkNode = AVAudioSinkNode { (timestep, frames, audioBufferList) -> OSStatus in
    let ptr = audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mData?.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float.self)
    var monoSamples = [Float]()
    monoSamples.append(contentsOf: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: Int(frames)))
    self.page = monoSamples.
    for frame in 0..<frames {
          print("sink: " + String(monoSamples[Int(frame)]))
        }
    return noErr
}
// AVAudioEngine connections

engine.attach(sinkNode)
// Audio input is passed to the AVAudioSinkNode and the [Float] array is pased to the AVAudioSourceNode through the _page_ variable
engine.connect(input, to: sinkNode, format: formatt)

engine.attach(srcNode)

engine.connect(srcNode,
                   to: engine.mainMixerNode,
                   format: format)

engine.connect(engine.mainMixerNode,
                   to: engine.outputNode,
                   format: format)

// The AVAudioSourceNode access the self.page array through the getSinalElement() function.
private func getSignalElement() -> Float {
    return page.isEmpty ? 0 : page.removeFirst()
}
```

This approach made it possible to play the audio through the AVAudioSourceNode, but, the audio stops playing after a few seconds (even though, I still successfully get the self.page array in AVAudioSourceNode) and the app finally crashes.

##### 2 strategy

In a similar approach, I used `installtap`
engine.attach(srcNode)

```
    engine.connect(srcNode,
                   to: engine.mainMixerNode,
                   format: format)

    engine.connect(engine.mainMixerNode,
                   to: engine.outputNode,
                   format: format)
    input.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize:1024, format:formatt, block: { [weak self] buffer, when in
        let arraySize = Int(buffer.frameLength)
        let samples = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData![0], count:arraySize))
        self!.page = samples
    })

// The AVAudioSourceNode access the self.page array through the getSinalElement() function.
private func getSignalElement() -> Float {
    return page.isEmpty ? 0 : page.removeFirst()
}
```

The outcome after implementing *Second strategy* is the same as in *First strategy*. Which can be the issues making these approaches fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AvAudioEngine().inputNode` like following:

```
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    private lazy var srcNode = AVAudioSourceNode { _, _, frameCount, audioBufferList -> OSStatus in
    
    return noErr
    }
    // Attach First
    engine.attach(srcNode)
    // Then connect nodes

    let input = engine.inputNode

    engine.connect(input, to: srcNode, format: input.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
```

It is important to use `input.inputFormat(...)` as format type.

Comment: Hi @Esmaeil, thanks for you answer. I tried it, but it crashes with _reason: 'required condition is false: [nodes containsObject: node1] && [nodes containsObject: node2]'_.  Does it crash for you? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Because you need to attach nodes to engine first, then connect them. I update the example for you.

Comment: even in this case I get a crash as soon as I run the app: _exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: inDestImpl->NumberInputs() > 0 || graphNodeDest->CanResizeNumberOfInputs()'_ Didn't you get the crash?

Comment: I check the [Apple Example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/equalizing_audio_with_vdsp) and it do jobs in following order: From AudioUtilities it getAudioSamples() then create waveform over these samples. But you need to make these samples yourself from microphone. To do it you need to add a installTap on inputNode and get samples of microphone. You can find a good tutorial on [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21672160-avaudioengine-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)

Comment: I updated the issue description. In the past, I tried to implement this by using `AvAudioSinkNode`, but as described in the description, I had some issues. The same issues have been observed by using `installTap`. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
   do{
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .defaultToSpeaker,.allowBluetoothA2DP,.allowAirPlay,.allowBluetooth])
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    engine.attach(player)
    //Add this only you want putch
    let pitch = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
    
   // pitch.pitch = 1000 //Filtered Voice
    //pitch.rate = 1 //Normal rate
    
    // engine.attach(pitch)
    engine.attach(srcNode)
    
    engine.connect(srcNode,
                   to: engine.mainMixerNode,
                   format: engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
    
    engine.connect(engine.mainMixerNode,
                   to: engine.outputNode,
                   format: engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))
    engine.prepare()
    
    
    engine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 512, format: engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        //   self.player.scheduleBuffer(buffer)
        let arraySize = Int(buffer.frameLength)
        let samples = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData![0], count:arraySize))
        self.page = samples
        print("samples",samples)
    }
    
    
    engine.mainMixerNode.outputVolume = 0.5
```

Comment: This is the code where I am using and getting the audio input from mic and applying the filters to it with this sample code https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/equalizing_audio_with_vdsp but app getting crash